# Difference between "Treat others as: you would like to be treated or you would like others to treat you."?

Tags: phrase-usage

As a non-native English speaker, I can not perceive the difference (in terms of language usage) between the following sentences.

1. Treat others as you would like to be treated.
2. Treat others as you would like others to treat you.

In my point of view, both sentences convey the same message. However, using a grammar reviewer to check them, it seems that the second one is more appropriate. I would like to understand why? Can anyone explain the difference to me? Thank you

Comment: Both are totally grammatical. The second variant is arguably more mellifluous, is better balanced. 'Merely' style considerations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is slightly more formal too, a little more appropriate to a formal essay perhaps.

Comment: What does "using a grammar reviewer to check them" refer to? Software or a human being? Some grammar software and even human beings strongly dislike the passive voice (arguably on dubious grounds but I shouldn't get into this here), which might lead them to prefer 2. But as said, both are grammatical even if you may have stylistic reasons to prefer one over the other.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, you should be posting questions like this on [ell.se] in my opinion (based on the description of this site in the [tour].